# Replace text in file regardless of the end of the line

Tags: c#, text, replace

I've been working on a tool to modify a text file to change graphics settings for a game. A few examples of the settings are as follows:

```
sg.ShadowQuality=0
ResolutionSizeX=1440
ResolutionSizeY=1080
bUseVSync=False
```

I want to be able to find sg.ShadowQuality=(rest of line, regardless of what is after this text), and replace it. This is so that a user can set this to say, 10 then 1 without having to check for 10 and 1 etc.
Basically, I'm try to find out what I need to use to find/replace a string in a text file without knowing the end of the string.
My current code looks like:

```
FileInfo GameUserSettings = new FileInfo(@SD + GUSDirectory);
GameUserSettings.IsReadOnly = false;
string text = File.ReadAllText(SD + GUSDirectory);
text = text.Replace("sg.ShadowQuality=0", "sg.ShadowQuality=" + Shadows.Value.ToString());
File.WriteAllText(SD + GUSDirectory, text);
text = text.Replace("sg.ShadowQuality=1", "sg.ShadowQuality=" + Shadows.Value.ToString());
File.WriteAllText(SD + GUSDirectory, text);
```

SD + GUSDirectory is the location of the text file.
The file must have readonly Off to be edited, otherwise the game can revert the settings back, hence the need for this.(It is turned back to readonly On after any change, its just not included in this code provided)

Comment: This looks like it's basically an INI file, so you want want to consider just using a library (e.g. [IniParser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ini-parser/)).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like you do, if you use a regular expression to match all the line

```
FileInfo gameUserSettings = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(@SD, GUSDirectory)); //name local varaible in camelCase, use Path.Combine to combine paths
gameUserSettings.IsReadOnly = false;

string text = File.ReadAllText(gameUserSettings.FullName); //use the fileinfo you just made rather than make the path again

text = Regex.Replace(text, "^sg[.]ShadowQuality=.*$", $"sg.ShadowQuality={Shadows.Value}", RegexOptions.Multiline); //note switch to interpolated strings

File.WriteAllText(gameUserSettings.FullName, text);
```

That regex is a Multiline one (so ^ and $ have altered meanings):

```
^sg[.]ShadowQuality=.*$
```

- start of line `^` (not start of input)
- followed by `sg`
- followed by period `.` (in a character class it loses its "any character" meaning)
- followed by `ShadowQuality=`
- followed by any number of any character(`.*`)
- followed by end of line `$` (not end of input)

The vital bit is "any number of any character" that can cope with the vlaue in the file being `1`, `2`, `7`, `hello` and so on..

The replacement is:

```
$"sg.ShadowQuality={Shadows.Value}"
```

This is an interpolated string; a neater way of representing strings that mix constant content (hardcoded chars) and variable content. When a `$tring` contains a `{` that "breaks out" of the string and back into normal c# code so you can write code that resolves to values that will be included in the string -> if `Shadows.Value` is for example a `decimal?` of `1.23` it will become 1.23

You can format data too; calling for `$"to one dp is {Shadows.Value:F1}"` would produce *"to one dp is 1.2"* - the 1.23 is formatted to 1 decimal place by the `F1`, just like calling `Shadows.Value.ToString("F1")` would

Comment: I did something similar and read all settings into a dictionary, without the values. Then the user can change values and finally I write all settings back into a file.  Using regular expressions may work as well. My project is public and you can access the files here: https://github.com/RudolfJan/ToolkitForTSW/tree/master/ToolkitForTSW/Settings CSettingsManager is the class to start.